# Is it possible to create/send an Outbound-Email mailing from the CD?

Tags: content-delivery, outbound-email

I am trying to create/send an Outbound-Email mailing after I register a contact via a Contact Us page, I am checking the API and documentation but I cannot find a sample or documentation about how to accomplish it.

Is there any Event System that probably I can use when a Contact is synchronized?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is [triggered mailings](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_B05DA8B12EC94A53B78624BF0F17083B) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

To send a single mail to the new Contact, you can specify a notification Page URI in the `contact.Save` call like this:

```cs
string notificationPageUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subscribe.NotificationPageUri"];
contact.Save(notificationPageUri ?? String.Empty);
```

But a triggered mailing is specifically for generic situations like Contact registration or performing an action (like clicking a link).

There are no events that run on creation of Contacts, so there is nothing you can hook into that way. I once tried a *hack* by using a TBB in the confirmation email Page Template, but if I remember correctly, that is rendered only when it is tested and the rendered result is used for the mail, so it didn't even work.